# angular ng-repeat - each item in collection repeating per number of items in collection (weird)

Tags: angularjs

I am having a weird issue trying to spit out some data into a table using angular's ng-repeat directive.

It seems to be repeating a each item in the collection per number of items in the collection.  So in this example I have five items, each item is repeated five times, rather than spitting out each of the five items in the collection just once.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Boovius/pZkrq/6/

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller='channelsCtrl'>
    <table>
            <tr ng-repeat='channel in channels'>
                <td >{{channel.title}}</td>
                <td >
                    <button type='button' class='btn-danger'>Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>  
</div>

function channelsCtrl($scope) {

var data = [{
    "title": "Sports"
}, {
    "title": "Adventure" }, 
{
    "title": "Shorts"}, 
{
   "title": "Beauty"}, 
{
    "title": "Spirituality"
}]


$scope.channels = data;


}
```

Comment: Why does this look so much like a recruitment test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing one of the angular references either in Frameworks and Extensions or External resources.